# datetime asp mvc 4 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, razor

As you can see here I have an editor for a date. the problem is that when I run my application and try to fill the date field I can't choose a date which day is `> 12` (I tried to reverse the position of day and month but it didn't work). How can I solve this?

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <label>Date de fin :</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date_fin)
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the format is MM/dd/YYYY ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server has a different locale for parsing the information you're inputting. You might want to consider separating out your day/month/year fields or enhance the interface for the users.

Take a look at this for example: http://www.nickharris.net/2010/08/asp-net-mvc-editor-template-for-jquery-datepicker/

EDIT: To figure out what culture/locale you're in write out this somewhere: `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name`

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your web.config file, and replace the "da-DK" with the ID of the CultureInfo (country/language) your application is supposed to run with:

```
  <system.web>
        <globalization culture="da-DK" uiCulture="da-DK"/>
```